# Latex function diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math,arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach[count=\i] \lseti/\lsetmi in {{A}/{$a$,$b$,$c$},{B}/{5,6,$z$}} {
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=\lseti, x=2cm, y=0.5cm]
        \foreach[count=\j] \lj in \lsetmi {
            \node[minimum width=1em] (n-\j-\lseti) at (\i,-\j) {\lj};
        }
        \end{scope}
        \node[ellipse, draw, fit=(\lseti), label={above:$\lseti$}] {};
    }
    \draw[->] (n-1-A) -- (n-1-B);
    \draw[->] (n-2-A) -- (n-2-B);
    \draw[->] (n-3-A) -- (n-3-B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Let the code above. It generates a diagram of a function f. How can I draw an arrow from the label A to the label B which has the letter f above? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give the labels names and connect them.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach[count=\i] \lseti/\lsetmi in {A/{$a$,$b$,$c$},B/{5,6,$z$}} {
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=\lseti, x=2cm, y=0.5cm]
        \foreach[count=\j] \lj in \lsetmi {
            \node[minimum width=1em] (n-\j-\lseti) at (\i,-\j) {\lj};
        }
        \end{scope}
        \node[ellipse, draw, fit=(\lseti), 
        label={[name=l-\lseti]above:$\lseti$}] {};
    }
    \draw[->] (n-1-A) -- (n-1-B);
    \draw[->] (n-2-A) -- (n-2-B);
    \draw[->] (n-3-A) -- (n-3-B);
    \draw[->] (l-A) -- node[above]{$f$}(l-A.center-|l-B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a complement to [user1146332's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/538052/194703). If you want to have the vertical alignment proper, it is arguably even better to use `anchor=base` and to give the nodes some `text height` and `text depth` since this works also with characters that go below the baseline.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach[count=\i] \lseti/\lsetmi in {A/{$a$,$b$,$g$},B/{5,6,$z$}} {
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=\lseti, x=2cm, y=0.5cm]
        \foreach[count=\j] \lj in \lsetmi {
            \node[minimum width=1em,anchor=base,text height=1.4ex,text
            depth=0.25ex] (n-\j-\lseti) 
            at (\i,-\j) {\lj};
        }
        \end{scope}
        \node[ellipse, draw, fit=(\lseti), 
        label={[name=l-\lseti]above:$\lseti$}] {};
    }
    \draw[->] (n-1-A) -- (n-1-B);
    \draw[->] (n-2-A) -- (n-2-B);
    \draw[->] (n-3-A) -- (n-3-B);
    \draw[->] (l-A) -- node[above]{$f$}(l-B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Indeed that's the most general case. Btw I set the text height implicitly with `vphantom`.

Comment: @user1146332 `\vphantom` sets the minimum height but not the absolute text height, but it is definitely a step in the right direction, so +1.

Comment: If one wanted to name the sets something other than $A$ and $B$, for example $dom(f)$ and $range(f)$, how could the code be adjusted?

Answer (score 3):

As a little complement to Schrödinger's answer:

If the figure is placed into a text rich context the reader's impression will most likely be disturbed because of the different vertical alignment of the characters.

To get the vertical alignment right you can set the anchor of the nodes to the baseline (i.e. `base`) of the characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    elems/.style = {
        minimum width=1.4em,
        anchor=base
    },
    helper/.style = {
        help lines, 
        red, 
        shorten <=-1cm, 
        shorten >= -1cm
    }
]
    \foreach[count=\i] \lseti/\lsetmi in {{A}/{$a$,$b$,$c$},{B}/{5,6,$z$}} {
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=\lseti, x=2cm, y=0.5cm]
            \foreach[count=\j] \lj in \lsetmi {
                \node[elems] (n-\j-\lseti) at (\i,-\j) {\vphantom{5}\lj};
            }
        \end{scope}
        \node[ellipse, draw, fit=(\lseti), label={[elems, yshift=0.25em, name=\lseti]$\lseti$}]  {};
    }

    \draw[->] (A) -- node[above]{$f$} (B);
    \draw[helper](A.base) -- (B.base);

    \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
        \draw[->] (n-\i-A) -- (n-\i-B);
        \draw[helper](n-\i-A.base) -- (n-\i-B.base);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```