# Pad beginning and end of tikz arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows, padding

I am making a function arrow diagram and notice that my arrows are "touching" the numbers at both ends:

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    >=stealth,
    bullet/.style=
    {
        fill=black,
        circle,
        minimum width=1pt,
        inner sep=1pt
    },
    -latex/.style=
    {
        ->,
        thick,
        shorten <=2pt,
        shorten >=2pt
    },
    every fit/.style=
    {
        ellipse,
        draw,
        inner sep=0pt
    }
]
    \coordinate (e) at (0.25,0);
    
    %Draw bullets and labels
    \foreach \y/\l in {1/a, 2/b, 3/c, 4/d}
    {
        \draw node[] at (0,\y) {$\l$};
        \coordinate(a\y) at (0,\y) {};
    }
    \foreach \y/\l in {1/x, 2/y, 3/z, 4/w}
    {
        \draw node[] at (4,\y) {$\l$};
        \coordinate (b\y) at (4,\y) {};
    }
    
    %Draw ellipses
    \node
    [
        draw,
        fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        label={[name=l-dom(f)]above:$\dom(f)$}
    ] {} ;
    \node
    [
        draw,
        fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        label={[name=l-range(f)]above:$\range(f)$}
    ] {} ;
        
    %Draw arrows
    \draw[-latex] (a1)+(e) -- (b3);
    \draw[-latex] (a2)+(e) -- (b4);
    \draw[-latex] (a3)+(e) -- (b3);
    \draw[-latex] (a4)+(e) -- (b1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

As you can see, I defined a coordinate (e) to be (0.25,0), which is meant to be used as horizontal padding, and I added that to the points in the domain which worked:

[image]

Notice the arrows look better, beginning slightly to the right of the points in the domain.

However, next I tried fixing the arrows at the right side. Unfortunately, subtracting this coordinate (e) from the points in the range did not work and led to an error. Does anyone know why, and how to fix this?

One more request: I would love to draw an arrow connecting $dom(f)$ to $range(f)$, similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538039/latex-function-diagram).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would draw your diagram on the following way:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, 
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 4mm and 44mm,
every fit/.style = {ellipse, draw,
                    minimum width=2cm, inner sep=0pt,
                    node contents={}
                    },
     start chain = going below,
                        ]
%Draw labels
\foreach \i/\j [count=\n] in {d/w, c/z, b/y, a/d}
{
    \node[on chain]     (a\n) {$\i$};
    \node[right=of a\n] (b\n) {$\j$};
}
%Draw ellipses
\node
[
    fit=(a1) (a4),
    label={[name=dom]:$\dom(f)$}
];
\node
[
    fit=(b1) (b4),
    label={[name=range]:$\range(f)$}
];

%Draw arrows
\foreach \i/\j in {a1/b4, a2/b2, a3/b1, a4/b2}    % changed
  \draw[-stealth, semithick] (\i) -- (\j);
% added
\draw[-stealth, semithick] (dom) -- node[above, font=\footnotesize] {text}    (range);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I remove from your MWE all style definitions not used in your diagram, merge loops for drawing nodes in ellipses, and use library `chains` for positioning  of nodes in the both ellipses. Also arrows are drawn a bit different, now their heads at node "z" not touch each other.

[image]

**Edit:**
Added is text above arrow between labels above ellipse. See MWE and produced image above)

If you may prefer, text be in arrow. In this case code for this arrows is:

```
\draw[-stealth, semithick] (dom) -- node[fill=white, font=\footnotesize] {text}    (range);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Zarko! Is it possible to add a node midway above the arrow connecting `dom` to `range` that is labeled `$f$`?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree, of course. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks very much! I gave the answer to you. I understand how you got rid of the styles that were unused, and how you merged the loops. I would love it if you could explain a little bit about how the "chaining" worked for this example. One slight downside I found - while the domain and range values are centered in the ellipse in this example, if you let the values have different lengths (e.g. $4$ and $100$ in the range, then the $100$ will be centered horizontally in the ellipse, but the $4$ will be a bit to the left of center.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree, the best description how  `chains`  work you can find in `tikz` package documentation,  chapter *48 Chains*, page 600, specially section *48.3 Nodes on a Chain*. Shortly, nodes in chain are follows each other in distances defined by `node distance` in direction defined by `start chain = <direction>` in `tikzpicture` options (or in `\tikzset` setting). This node should contain option `on chain`.  Thanks to this features loop. which defines nodes in ellipsis, is simple, not need to explicit definition of their positioning, loop only care for nodes content and their naming.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes.geometric}

\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    >=stealth,
    bullet/.style=
    {
        fill=black,
        circle,
        minimum width=1pt,
        inner sep=1pt
    },
    -latex/.style=
    {
        ->,
        thick
    },
    every fit/.style=
    {
        ellipse,
        draw,
        inner sep=0pt
    }
]
    %Draw bullets and labels
    \foreach \y/\l in {1/a, 2/b, 3/c, 4/d}
    {
        \draw node (a\y) at (0,\y) {$\l$};
        \coordinate(a\y') at (0,\y) {}; % to keep the ellipse slim
    }
    \foreach \y/\l in {1/x, 2/y, 3/z, 4/w}
    {
        \draw node (b\y) at (4,\y) {$\l$};
        \coordinate (b\y') at (4,\y) {}; % to keep the ellipse slim
    }

    %Draw ellipses
    \node
    [
        draw,
        fit=(a1') (a4'),
        minimum width=2cm,
        label={[name=l-dom(f)]above:$\dom(f)$}
    ] {} ;
    \node
    [
        draw,
        fit=(b1') (b4'),
        minimum width=2cm,
        label={[name=l-range(f)]above:$\range(f)$}
    ] {} ;

    %Draw arrows
    \foreach \i/\j in {a1/b3, a2/b4, a3/b3, a4/b1, {{l-dom(f)}}/{{l-range(f)}}} {
      \draw[-latex] (\i.east) -- (\j.west);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And what's the easiest way to draw an arrow connecting $dom(f)$ to $range(f)$?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Answer updated. An arrow from `l-dom(f)` to `l-range(f)` is added.

Comment: Thanks Muzimuzhi! Last question - how could I add a node midway above the arrow connecting `l-dom(f)` to `l-range(f)` that is labeled `$f$`?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree See https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/midway or https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz%5D+midway+node